# PHP MySQL simple script not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm just trying to retrieve an entry from a table called categories.

```
<?php
  $conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
  $sql  = "SELECT description FROM categories WHERE STRCMP(id,:id)=0";
  $st   = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $st->bindValue(":id", $results['article']->category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $st->execute();
  $desc  = $st->fetch();
  $conn = null;
  if ($desc)
      {?>
        <li><a href="index.php?action=viewByCategory&amp;category=<?php echo $results['article']->category?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($desc)?></a></li>
<?php}?>
```

Comment: try some basic debugging. Does `prepare()` return false?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: do a `print_r($desc);` . what does that return?. also make sure `$results['article']->category` has something there

Comment: [`PDO::fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) `Fetches a row ...`, not the column, so you would need to do `$desc['description']`

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I get the same error that I post in my sql config file, but i know for sure the file is good because I'm using it on other pages with other tables, from the same db. Also, the pages are in the same folder.

Comment: Still not working. :'(

Comment: @Akintunde `fetchAll()` returns [`Returns an array containing all of the result set rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), so they would need `$desc[0]['description']` not `$desc['description']`

Comment: well said @Sean ..

Comment: It hasn't worked anyways. Could it be from my sql configuration file ?

Comment: It's working when i'm accesing it from another file in the same folder, and i'm also requiring this config file.

Comment: after establishing connection, check if something went wrong? `!$conn`

Comment: You mention a `error` in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503945/php-mysql-simple-script-not-working?noredirect=1#comment81963765_47503945). Do you have an error message that you are hiding from us? Is this a test to see if we can read you mind?

Comment: This is the error message "syntax error, unexpected end of file"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, finally I got it. You're not supposed to close brackets like this in php

```
<?php? ?>
```